# Why the following apache htaccess code does not return me my page?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have requested a url "http://mydomain/testscripts/php_Env"

I have a file php_Env.php in my testscripts folder..

My htaccess is as follows

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    # Existing File
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    # Existing Directory
RewriteRule    ^(php_([a-zA-Z_]+))$  $1.php   [NC,L]
```

When running it, browser returns me

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log
```

What i wanted to do was if the request file is not a directory and not a file , request the file. Where did I go wrong in the htaccess ?

Comment: Can you check the server logs? You also want to put `RewriteBase /testscripts/` before your rules.

Comment: What is the error? Check your logs - a 500 error will have a reason.

Comment: "C:/wamp/www/testscripts/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters"           That's the error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with no extraneous spaces and comments:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(php_([a-zA-Z_]+))$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

If it works, you can add back the comments (maybe leave just one space between the last character in the rule and the `#` sign).